# Speeding up rendering of Windows Form elements

Tags: c#, arrays, windows, winforms, optimization

I'm creating app with a lot of data in it,and some data should be added to FlowLayourPanel.
I add them all in using for,and at the end of each FOR cycle.I have tested extreme values like having 1000 members of array,and they should all render on screen.
I multithreaded and it works ultra fast(sorting them,calculating maximum,minimum and sum) but when it needs to be displayed it takes good 2 seconds,maybe even 3 and i cant multithread it as Windows Form doesnt allow me to.

My users will not have 1000 members in array,but i must try it and it must work with that much.

Is there any way it will work?

It lags on this moment,without this part of code it works instantly(4 ms)

```
PFlow.Controls.Add(Dat[i]);
```

PFlow is flowlayoutpanel and Dat[i] is data
Data is actually a class containing 5 variables,one more array and few functions.

Also when im scrolling very fast trough FlowLayoutPanel and then stops,it freezes the whole program for 2 seconds,like its rendering it all again

Comment: Enabling double buffering may help with the rendering issues.

Comment: did it,still same,just doesn't flicker when scrolling

Comment: @rfmodulator Do you maybe know a way to multithread it,at least?

Comment: You can't draw on or interact from a different thread than the one that owns the FLP. If you're doing a bunch of extra stuff in your loop you might could offload that to parallel processes.... I would need to see more code to help beyond the scrolling issues.

Comment: @rfmodulator I did that,user     Parallel.For
then i return to main thread and add it to parent,and thats where its slow

Comment: Inside your Parallel.For logic, you might try calling `PFlow.Invoke(...)` ...passing a delegate to add the item... only one will execute at a time, but it may improve your performance, or the appearance of it.

Comment: @rfmodulator thank you i will try it,its just bummer that they dont allow you do fully optimize it... :(

Comment: Instead of looping through `Dat` you might also try something like `PFlow.SuspendLayout(); PFlow.Controls.AddRange(Dat); PFlow.ResumeLayout();`

Comment: `freezes ...m for 2 seconds,like its rendering it all again` More likely drawing it for the first time.  Windows isnt going to draw something which isnt even on screen yet.

Comment: @rfmodulator hmmm i will try it,but the problem is i have 2 loops,with different data types.Ill think how to add it all :)

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow Oh that gives me an idea,not to add stuff that are not on screen?

Comment: @DusanTodorovic `Dat` must be a collection of `Control`s so you can do `AddRange()` without issue after `Dat` is populated.

Comment: @rfmodulator i have array of buttons and labels,all custom made so that its painted orange and it has only one line below it.I will think of a way to add it to some kind of array

Comment: @rfmodulator thank you man,i added them all in one list of Collections and it works perfectly
Well not perfect but it doesnt lag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I solved the problem and now it's instant.

It goes like this:

```
List<Control> lis = new List<Control>();
Parallel.For(/* Populate lis */);
PFlow.Controls.AddRange(lis.ToArray());
```